# "The place I was born" vs. "The place I was born in"

Tags: grammaticality, relative-clauses, omissibility

> This is the place where I was born. [1]

I can omit **where** & keep the antecedent **place** :

> This is the place I was born. [1a]

I can omit the antecedent **place** and keep the relative word **where** :

> This is where I was born. [1b]

I can replace **where** with *"preposition + which"* :

> This is the place in which I was born. [2]

I can place the preposition at the end :

> This is the place which I was born in. [2a]

I can omit **which** from this sentence :

> This is the place I was born in. [2b]

Do both the sentences, **[1a] and [2b]**, sound good?

Answer (score 1):

- *This is the place where I was born*. No need for in, for geography.
- Let's say you were born in an ugly hospital building and **you want to stress that**:
- This is place I was born **in.** [to be born inside a location]
- This is the family I was born **into.** [to be born into a family]

Unlike: I don't know where they are at.

The "at" is always non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

All those examples sound natural, except for [2] and [2a].

> This is the place in which I was born. [2]
>
> This is the place which I was born in. [2a]

[2] sounds formal, and [2a] sounds formal and a bit awkward to my ears if not ungrammatical.

That said, [2a] might work in British English.

Comment: What's about [1a] & [2b]?

Comment: "All those examples" include both of them.

Comment: You say "This is the place I was born" and "This is the place I was born in" are okay. Is **in** optional ?

Comment: Yes, it's optional.

Comment: To my British ear, [2] and [2a] both sound normal. I would not be surprised to hear [1a] and [2b]. You may wish to bear in mind that the implied preposition in "where" is supplied by the listener and is not restricted to "in".

Comment: @Greybeard Thought so, although I'm not too familiar with BrE.

Comment: In the UK, until quite recently, 'This is the place I was born' would have been seen as distinctly American in flavour.

Comment: There is no reason to say: in which I was born, unless, for example, it is a hospital. It is awkward, though, even there....

Answer (score 0):

Between the two, 1a sounds natural in a conversational sense while 2b violates the somewhat archaic prohibition of ending a sentence with a preposition which might strike the hearer as incorrect, as every one of my English teachers would agree.